# How to add custom precompiled contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, precompiled-contracts

I want to implement some features as precompiled contracts in Ethereum. I read some articles and the [contract code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go), but I still don't know how to do this.

Is there's a tutorial from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good reference that do a new pre-compile contract for Ethereum next hardfork named `Istanbul`

https://github.com/keep-network/go-ethereum/pull/4/files

Basically, you only need to implement two methods of pre-compiled contract interface

1. **RequiredGas**(): to define how many gas user need to pay when calling the pre-compiled contract.
2. **Run**(): write your code to do the thing that you want the pre-compiled contract will do.

By the way, the issue for us is official solidity compiler might not support our pre-compiled function then the only way that user can use our pre-compiled function is use inline assembly code in solidity smart contract.

Hope this will give you some clue to start!

Comment: If you make sure that your preconpiled contact follows the ABI spec, then you can simply treat it as a contact in solidity, no assembly required